# default constructor for derived class is not provided by compiler

Tags: c++

I have a code where in I am deriving one class from library class whose default constructor is defined in library. I am not defining any default constructor and as per my understanding C++ compiler should provide it for me but I am getting error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'derived::derived()'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

My code looks like below code snippet

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public :
    base()
    {
        ;
    }
};

class derived : public base
{
    public :
    derived(int) : base()
    {
        ;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    derived obj;
}
```

Can someone please explain me why default constructor is not generated here by compiler ?

Thanks In advance.

Comment: You need to pass an argument like this: `derived obj(i);`

Answer (score 0):

Because the default constructor is only generated if you don't add any other non-default constructors.

---

If you want, you can even look it up in the C++ standard at §12.1/4

> A *default* constructor for a class `X` is a constructor of class `X`
>   that either has no parameters or else each parameter that is not a
>   function parameter pack has a default argument. **If there is no
>   user-declared constructor for class `X`**, a constructor having no
>   parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (...).

Comment: Any idea why ? why not compiler just provide regular default constructor in case user has given other non-default constructor ?

Comment: @noname: Because that's the way C++ works. The compiler implements the C++ language and not something else.

Comment: @noname When you've defined a non-default constructor, the probability is very high that the compiler-generated default constructor would do something wrong. In the few cases that it would be correct, it's trivial to add it explicitly.